# How to setup real device (iPhone5) in xCode5

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

I've just upgraged to xCode5 from xCode4, but my iPhone becomes not recognised in xCode5, and after I connect iPhone again, no info pop out to ask me setup my iPhone but xCode4 does.

How to make xCode5 recognise my device again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Organizer (Cmd-Shift-2) and you'll see your device listed there.

Click on the "Use for Development" button that appears for your device.

If the "Use for Development" button doesn't appear, your device is probably still on iOS 6 and Xcode 5 (which has the iOS 7 SDK) might not want to work with a device that has an older OS on it.

Comment: Dautemann, hi Michael, thanks for your answer, could you please tell me how "Go to Organizer" ? My iPhone5 has updated to iOS7.0.2